# C# how to compare two List<string> and get value of duplicated element

Tags: c#

I've got two `List<string>`, one contains user's `IDs` and their emails, second contains only emails. I am trying to find duplicated emails from second list in the first list, and input email's IDs in a variable.

Example:
1st List content:

```
emailswithIDs = List<string> {1, abc@gmail.com, 2, abcd@gmail.com, 3, abcde@gmail.com
```

2nd List content:

```
emails = List<string> {abcd@gmail.com}
```

So I'd like to make variable "IDs" which would contain "2" as it is the ID of duplicated email.

I have tried:

```
var IDs = emails.Intersect(emailswithIDs);
```

But obviously it will only get the duplicated string, and I need to get the email's ID value.

Comment: Did you review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148175/compare-two-liststring-and-print-the-duplicates)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing ids and values in the same `List<string>` is *not a good practice*. Let's build a dictionary (i.e. mail - id correspondence): `mail` will be a `Key` and `id` will be a `Value`:

```
  Dictionary<string, string> emailToId = new Dictionary<string, string>(
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  for (int i = 0; i < emailswithIDs.Count; i += 2) 
    emailToId.Add(emailswithIDs[i + 1], emailswithIDs[i]);
```

Then you can easily query if item in `emails` exists in `emailToId`:

```
  var ids = emails
    .Where(email => emailToId.ContainsKey(email))
    .Select(email => emailToId[email]);
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F7rFaB)

Comment: I know that it is not a good practice, but unfortunately both of the lists that I've got are created by two different APIs, I am trying to compile the data for further use in one of the APIs.

Comment: @Pastooh: well, you can get data from the API, but then turn list into a dictionary and from that moment on work with the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've changed my code a bit and your answer resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
List<string> emailsWithIDs = new List<string> { "1", "abc@gmail.com", "2", "abcd@gmail.com", "3", "abcde@gmail.com", "4", "abcde@gmail.com"};
List<string> emails = new List<string> { "abcd@gmail.com" };
List<string> IDs = new List<string>();

for(int i=0; i<emailsWithIDs.Count(); i+=2)
{
    for(int j=0; j<emails.Count(); j++)
    {
        if(emailsWithIDs[i+1] == emails[j])
        {
            IDs.Add(emailsWithIDs[i]);
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(IDs.Count());

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Let's say beginner technique )

Answer (score 0):

If finding an email address at index `n` and you can guarantee that element at `n-1` is the corresponding id, you can do something like this:

```c#
// For each entry in emails find the index of the same string
// In the emailswithIDs list, then take n-1 because that
// represents the index of the id in emailswithIDs
var duplicateEmailIndices = emails
    .Select(x => emailswithIDs.IndexOf(x))
    .Where(x => x >= 1)
    .Select(x => x - 1);

// Get the entries from emailswithIDs at each index given
// in duplicateEmailIndices
var duplicateIds = emailswithIDs.Where((id, index) => duplicateEmailIndices.Contains(index));
```

This, of course, only provides a solution for the code as it is written currently. There are better solutions, such as `Dictionary`, as pointed out in another answer. It also assumes that the `emailswithIDs` list will *always* contain data in the order of `id, email, id, email...`